# Resource not found(error 404) in Azure AI Language Understanding app

Tags: json, azure, artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding

While doing a microsoft course (Azure AI Engineer Associate) i came across the `Error 404: resource not found`. I'm trying to make a language understanding bot. This is what shows for me:

```
PS C:\estudoAI\AI-102-AIEngineer\10b-clu-client-(preview)\C-Sharp\clock-client> dotnet run

Enter some text ('quit' to stop)
hello
Resource not found
Status: 404 (Resource Not Found)
ErrorCode: 404

Content:
{"error":{"code":"404","message": "Resource not found"}}

Headers:
apim-request-id: REDACTED
Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED
X-Content-Type-Options: REDACTED
Date: Wed, 04 Oct 2023 14:12:06 GMT
Content-Length: 56
Content-Type: application/json
```

---

I'm also putting in here the endpoint they gave me in the instruction(i followed all of the steps, but still couldn't make it), and the key(in a placeholder for privacy and safety reasons)

```
{
    "LSPredictionEndpoint":"https://studylanguageservice.cognitiveservices.azure.com/language/:analyze-conversations?api-version=2022-10-01-preview",
    "LSPredictionKey":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: alright, my bad. in the next questions ill provide it, in this case it had nothing to do with coding to be honest

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I just needed to make sure that the Resource Group and the Language Deployment were both in the same Region. It was a silly mistake due to the availability of the Microsoft Language Service Regions.